# Chrome store shareable developer site (like Google's Play)

Tags: chrome-web-store

When you are a paying developer in Google Play, you get a public shareable site, like:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=....
```

but when you are a paying developer in Chromestore, **does this happend?** I can't find the shareable link...

Something like what I see here:

```
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard
```

...but, shareable (that's not)

Comment: Offtopic, not really a programming question. This is more marketing than anything.

Comment: what StackExchange site should I use for this question?

Comment: @MarcB I say it is a valid question _here_, it was just badly tagged.

Comment: On topic, I think the answer is "no", but I'm not sure enough to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I've found that if your developer username is kind of unique (in my case: "germanger"), you can share this link:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/germanger?_category=extensions

Which is just a search.
Probably if there was another similar username, like: germanger123, this wouldn't work (it would show both user developed extensions)